# Is it possible to record/playback http trafic to a kerberized endpoint like yarn rest API with wiremock?

Tags: kerberos, wiremock

I've tried to use wiremock to record http exchanges between curl and a yarn rest API server but the kerberos negotiation failed (curl -negotiate ...  => Unauthorized).
Is there any way to do that ? Or am I doomed to record and map by hand for the tests?

Thanks in advance.
Patrice

Comment: You know that Kerberos is a security thing, right? Secure authentication over an insecure network. Includes **protection against "replay" attacks**. Which is close to what you are trying to do...

Comment: You need Kerberos creds to start the Kerberos negotiation. But then, the HTTP client should use a session token (signed cookie) to (1) avoid the overhead of Kerberos and (2) be able to switch servers in case of failover without reauthenticating. If you can "steal" the cookie, you can automate tests for the lifetime of that cookie.

Comment: Of course, I know what Kerberos is, I have the keytab with credentials and all works fine  with curl - negotiate. 
The idea is not to test the secure server, but to replace it with a mock. I can make all requests with curl, record the responses from the server and integrate them into my unit tests using wiremock. But it's boring ... hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Samson suggestion, I made a first request with "curl -negotiate" to register the "hadoop.auth" cookie.
Then I re-injected this cookie in each curl request using wiremock as proxy to register the trafic.

```
curl --verbose --cookie "hadoop.auth=XXXXXXX" -u : --compressed -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://yarn-server/ws/v1/cluster/apps" --proxy localhost:8080
```

Hope this helps somebody.
Patrice